# Getting duplicate output from GWMI cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I am getting a duplicate output when I type this command:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -ComputerName $computer | Where-Object name -Match explorer).GetOwner().User
```

It outputs

```
Username
Username
```

I just want it to output

```
Username
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: You obviously have 2 explorer processes running, so you're getting the owner for each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Select-Object -Unique` to grab only one instance of each distinct user name:

```
$Usernames = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process -ComputerName '.' | Where-Object Name -match explorer).GetOwner().User 
$Usernames = $Usernames |Select -Unique
```